# trim systemd package

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to trim down utilities provided by systemd because some of them are not so useful to me, e.g. graphical functions, systemd-analyze etc.

I searched online but most threads are talking about how to remove systemd completely.

Any ideas how to get rid of some components in systemd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do what you're looking for by specifying appropriate `--disable` flags for `./configure`. There are far too many flags to list here; you can see their definitions in [`configure.ac`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/configure.ac) or by running

```
./configure --help
```

(which may require running `./autogen.sh` first to generate the `configure` script).

You can check out distribution packages' build scripts too since they tend to de-activate certain features and split systemd up into multiple packages (*e.g.* [Debian's](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-systemd/systemd.git/tree/debian/rules)).